# How many free rewinds do you get in HarborMaster?

Tags: harbormaster

I noticed that HarborMaster for the iPad added a rewind feature. They sell rewinds which you can buy for real money. However, I also noticed that you can use some (one?) without purchasing anything.

My question is do I only get to use one free one? Will it recharge after some time? If so, how long does it usually take for it to recharge? Can I ever get more than 1 free one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this site](http://toucharcade.com/2010/09/08/harbor-master-hd-updated-with-clever-new-in-app-purchase/), you start off with 5, then get another another one every 1000 pieces of cargo you ship.

You can press the rewind button to find out how many rewinds you have left. You can then cancel it by pressing the back button so that it doesn't waste a rewind. It will also show you how much more cargo you need to deliver to get the next free rewind.

To see the rewind button, you must deliver at least 1 cargo. Thus, the easiest way to find out how many rewinds you have left is to start a game, dock the first boat, and purposely crash the next two boats that appear. Tap the rewind button, then press back.